# Generate new object with mapping Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a POST request in my controller Product like this:

```
[HttpPost("/product")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProduct([FromBody] ProductRequest productCreate)
{
    var response = await _productService.CreateProduct(_mapper.Map<Product>(productCreate));
    return Ok(_mapper.Map<ProductResponse>(response));
}
```

ProductRequest has the following structure:

```
public class ProductRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map this object ProductRequest to an object with Automapper named Product who has the following structure:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<ProductPrice> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

Where:
ProductRequest.Name => Product.Name
ProductRequest.Description => Product.Description

I know how to do that but I don't know how to use ProductRequest.Price and create a new instance of ProductPrice.Price.

ProductPrice has the following structure:

```
public class ProductPrice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }        
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

So when my Product reach the method Create in ProductService, this has a new object ProductPrice with the value of ProductRequest.Price in Product.ProductPrice.Price

Comment: Doesn't answer the question necessarily, but keep in mind that even the author of AutoMapper does not recommend mapping in the "viewmodel->domain" direction using the library, since that usually involves some knowledge other than pure mapping and can cause other issues.

Comment: @julealgon I didnt' know about that. One question I have a solution architecture like Web -> Business Logic -> Data and Entities (this last one referenced form all the other layers), so how can I send my request info from the web project to the business project if I don't map to an entity who both layers knows? Becouse I have my DTOs in Web layer

Comment: You'd still "map" from the Web to Business, but the suggestion is that you'd do that direction of the mapping manually, instead of using AutoMapper to do it. To be clear, I don't always follow that advice myself, but figured you'd be interested to know about it. There are many articles online talking about dangers and caveats when using AutoMapper to map into entities, especially if those are the same objects involved with EntityFramework.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the recommendation. I will follow this whenever is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a mapping profile such as this using `AfterMap` and relying on the mapper internally to map both the outer object as well as the inner one:

```cs
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<ProductRequest, ProductPrice>()
            .ForMember(p => p.StartDate, o => o.MapFrom(_ => DateTime.Now));

        this.CreateMap<ProductRequest, Product>()
            .AfterMap((request, product, context) =>
            {
                product.Prices = new() { context.Mapper.Map<ProductPrice>(request) };
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked fine! Can u explain me a little more this solution?

Comment: @iMSn20 "AfterMap" runs after the standard mapping finishes, but still happens as part of the main call. We wait for the object to be built, and then assign a new list with the mapped price to it after the fact. That part also uses the same mapper so that we can define a mapping between `ProductRequest` and `ProductPrice` and reuse it. This allows you to manage both mapping separately and avoids any manual construction code inside the mapping.